# How to handle logs from a package that I am using?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pytest

I created a python package that looks like this:

```
mypackage
    - mypackage
        - src
            - somesrc.py
        - tests
            - conftest.py
            - test_folder
                - sometest.py
```

In mypackage/src/somesrc.py I defined a logger like this:

```
# mypackage/src/somesrc.py 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

I wanted to try handling the logs from my app in the tests. 
I therefore created a new logger together as follows:

```
# mypackage/tests/conftest.py
logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

date_info = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
logfilename = '/tmp/filename' + date_info + '.log'
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfilename)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s -12s %(levelname)s -8s %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Which I found in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#).

Now as I am using mypackage/mypackage/src/somesrc.py in the test file I was expecting to get all logs from mypackage in the log file defined by the filehandler above. However, the only logs that the log file contains are the logs from sometest.py.

I dont understand because it is said from the docs that I should create logs from mypackage/src and that it would be handled by a handler defined in an application using my package. 
Does anyone knows what I missed?

When I run pytest on sometest.py it does show all logs both from the test and source file. I don't understand how I can do the same.

Comment: `somesrc.py` uses its own logger, so creating a "test" logger does not overwrite that one. You have to add your handler to the logger of the production code, or make that configurable.

Comment: Probably the best way is to use a [logging configuration](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging).

Comment: Thanks for your help. What is the "logger of the production code" ?

Comment: The logger in your `somesrc.py` and similar loggers, initialized using the module name.

Comment: OK I thought that each python library could send their own logs using their logger and then an application using some of these libraries could handle the logs of all its third-parties libraries. Is that not possible ? Edit: I thought that was actually the good practice

Comment: If the library uses the standard loggers named by the module name, as you do, you will know these names and can access and configure them in your application code, but you have to access them by their name.

Comment: OK thank you for your help but I think I will just give up for now. This logging library is just awful.